# ssh search for js injections text in files

Tags: file, search, ssh

My website was hacked and a lot of files now have js injections, that's why I need your help. Since am a beginner I dont know how to write commands in ssh, could somebody help me with a ssh command to find text in all files on the server.

My html files have this code -

```
<!--68c8c7--><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
```

BLA BLA CODE HERE

My php files have this:

```
<?
```

## 68c8c7

## /68c8c7

?>

And .htaccess has code similar to the html files. To be short they all have in common - "68c8c7". Is there any way to run a command that would look in all my files for "68c8c7" and save them to the file? And also it would awesome to search and replace, any thoughts on that?

Thank you,
Dan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -lrIi 68c8c7 $SEARCH_DIR > outputfile.txt
```

This should list all filenames under `$SEARCH_DIR` which contain the string `68c8c7` and store the result to `outputfile.txt`

**NOTE:** The grep command excludes all binary files, since based on your question I understood that you're only interested in source files.

Now if you would like to replace the string `68c8c7` with a blank in all these files, you could run this command in bash:

```
for file in $(cat outputfile.txt); do
    sed -i 's#68c8c7##gI' $file
done
```

**WARNING:** Just to be sure, do make a backup of the files before running the `sed` command to perform search-and-replace.

Comment: I decided not to replace, but manually go over files just not to cause any more troubles. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

replacing `68c8c7` will not do the trick. These strings are html-comment anyway.
One of my sites was hacked today the same way. I searched all infected files by a simple string-search >> `68c8c7`. It turned out that all my `.js` files contained the new function which writes the html for a new iframe when a page loads. Deleting the bad lines did not work, I had to completely remove all source from the web server and replace it by the backup-files on my laptop.

Googling ("`68c8c7` hack javascript") this phenomena returns a huge list of apparently infected websites. Any tips on how to protect my websites R welcome!!!
(Will setting the access-rights on the js-files to read-only do any good?)

Cheers,
Arthur

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I know that those are just comments. Stupid of me but I did not have any backups so I had to clean it up, which I did manually file by file from ftp logs. And needed this command to double check that everything is removed, I didn't replace, only searched for occurrences. But thank you anyway!